# Flutter web and SSR

Tags: flutter, server-side-rendering, flutter-web

I'm new in flutter and I want to implement SSR for my flutter web app. does Flutter web support SSR(server side rendering)?
how should I implement it?

Comment: I haven't actually worked with Flutter Web, but I do know it makes extensive use of `canvas` (to say the least). So my guess is that it's not possible.

Comment: find any solution ?

Answer (score 8):

That's not yet implemented, but you can follow this issue on Github for future info: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47600